# variable oxidation states

Tags: inorganic-chemistry, oxidation-state

which of the statements is true:

1. looking at the electronic configuration of an element, can the possible oxidation states/oxidation number of an elemnet be predicted.
   for example, the valence electronic configuration of nitrogen is 2s^2 2p^3. From this can we know all the possible oxidation states exhibited by the element nitrogen.

   ```
                               (OR)
   ```

2.We should first know all the compounds nitrogen can form, and then find the oxidation number of nitrogen in each compound, and then give all the possible oxidation states nitrogen can exhibit.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The oxidation numbers cannot be predicted from the structure of the atom. They are experimentally determined. Not much chance you predict that while nitrogen can get all integer oxidation numbers from $−3$ to $+5$, its neighbor oxygen can only have $−2$, $−1$, $0$, $+1$, $+2$ in known compounds. And then come fractional oxidation states...

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/121194/discussion-on-answer-by-maurice-variable-oxidation-states).